# Breaking out of this "for" loop while nested "if" statements

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, break

I'm trying to use a `break;` statement to exit a `for` loop.

```
final int NUM_USERS = 6;                     // Max Number of Users.
UserInfo[] users = new UserInfo[NUM_USERS];  // Array of Users.
int loginCounter = 0;                        // Counts bad login attempts.
int i = 0;                                   // Loop index variable.
String userRole = "";                        // Holds user's role text.

for (loginCounter = 1; loginCounter <= 3; ++loginCounter) {
        // Get User's Credentials.
        System.out.println("Enter Username: ");
        String username = input.next().toLowerCase();
        input.nextLine();                      // Allows User to enter password.
        System.out.println("Enter Password: ");
        String password = input.nextLine();

        String hash = sysLogin.convertToMd5(password);
        for (i = 0; i < users.length; ++i) {
            if (username.equals(users[i].getUsername())) {
                if (hash.equals(users[i].getHash())) {
                    userRole = users[i].getRole();
                    sysLogin.goodLogin();      // Prints Good Login message.
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                sysLogin.badLogin();           // Prints Bad Login message.
            }
        }
    }
```

**What is happening:**

The code will read in the `username` and `password`, verify it is a good login, then return to asking for the username and password, again.

**What is expected to happen:**

Once it hits a successful login, it sets `userRole` to the current User's role, displayed the `goodLogin` message, then exits the loop.

Comment: And what problems are you experiencing?

Comment: have you tried attaching a debugger and stepping through the code line by line to see where the unexpected result occurs?

Comment: Your break will only break out of the innre most `for` loop where you itterate the user list, it will not break out of the outtr loop.

Comment: I am using NetBeans IDE, and have debugged repeatedly. It outputs the Good Login message (I'll edit the original post) but ignores the `break;`. Does `break;` also apply to `if` statements? I thought they only applied to loops.

Comment: Your break statement breaks out of one of the for loops (the one that loops through each user), if you want to break out of the main for loop, add a label to it and call the break statement with the label. `label: for(...` and `break label;`

Comment: I see it now. I stared at the code for over an hour, and didn't remember I had a nested `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a label and break to that label ([Java example about labels in branches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)):

```
final int NUM_USERS = 6;                     // Max Number of Users.
UserInfo[] users = new UserInfo[NUM_USERS];  // Array of Users.
int loginCounter = 0;                        // Counts bad login attempts.
int i = 0;                                   // Loop index variable.
String userRole = "";                        // Holds user's role text.
OUTER:
for (loginCounter = 1; loginCounter <= 3; ++loginCounter) {
        // Get User's Credentials.
        System.out.println("Enter Username: ");
        String username = input.next().toLowerCase();
        input.nextLine();                      // Allows User to enter password.
        System.out.println("Enter Password: ");
        String password = input.nextLine();

        // Convert password to MD5 hash.
        String hash = sysLogin.convertToMd5(password);
        for (i = 0; i < users.length; ++i) {
            if (username.equals(users[i].getUsername())) {
                if (hash.equals(users[i].getHash())) {
                    userRole = users[i].getRole();
                    sysLogin.goodLogin();      // Prints Good Login message.
                    break OUTER;
                }
            else {
                sysLogin.badLogin();           // Prints Bad Login message.
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wow...I am special... I get what everyone was saying now. I forgot, I have a nested `for` loop. Thank you everyone. Marking question answered.

Comment: Please don't use this 80's coding style that relies on labels. It's considered very bad practice, to say the least. It also makes your code hard to debug and unmaintainable (difficult to modify) on the long run.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner this was a quick solution to the provided code. I didn't mean to refactor the code. There are many ways to implement the logic provided in the example, but there was a precise question - why the example provided doesn't work and how to fix

Answer (score 2):

the `break` will only break out of the inner for loop where you itterate the user list, and not the outer loop.

Try doing some thing like this

```
boolean login = false;
do {

    // Get User's Credentials.
    System.out.println("Enter Username: ");
    String username = input.next().toLowerCase();
    input.nextLine();                      // Allows User to enter password.
    System.out.println("Enter Password: ");
    String password = input.nextLine();

    // Convert password to MD5 hash.
    String hash = sysLogin.convertToMd5(password);
    for (i = 0; i < users.length; ++i) {
        if (username.equals(users[i].getUsername())) {
            if (hash.equals(users[i].getHash())) {

                login = true;

                userRole = users[i].getRole();
                sysLogin.goodLogin();      // Prints Good Login message.
                break;
            } else {

                sysLogin.badLogin();           // Prints Bad Login message.
            }
        }
    }
} while ( login == false && failCondition == false );
```

You would need to add back in the failure count to the loop, but this should give you a more expected result.

Answer (score 1):

The `break;` statement breaks the inner-most loop; the outer-most loop will continue executing.

In the outer-most loop, you would want to have a variable such as `bool success = false;`. Before breaking in the inner-most loop, assign `true`, and do a check in the outer-most loop like:

`if(success) break;`